# Why does this js-php generated location reference does not work in IE8?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Why does this js-php generated location reference does not work in IE8?

```
<script>
<?php
    session_start();
        $_SESSION['admintermorol']=false;
        echo "window.location='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."';";
?>
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What gets echoed?

Comment: Do you mean window.location.href ?

Comment: I've tried both versions @madflow. But what Dale answered works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you could do this with pure php, replace

```
echo "window.location='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."';";
```

with

```
exit(header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}\r\n"));
```

Sorry, that's slightly wrong

Move the code to the top of the page (not inside the script tag)

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['admintermorol']))
{
    exit(header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}\r\n"));
}
?>
```

Or (now I know) you can do this :-)

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['admintermorol'] = FALSE;
exit(header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}\r\n"));
?>
```

Comment: I believe the issue is with the `session_start()` call being in the 'middle' of the page, session_start() must be called before anything is sent to the browser.

Comment: It's okay, the objective of the file was to set the admintermorol on false and then return to the calling page.